# Time complexity for inner loop from 0 to i

Tags: time-complexity

Got code for time complexity analysis in practice test:

```
for i ​in​ 0..n-1:
    ​for​ j ​in​ 0..i:
```

The answer wrote the complexity for this as O(n^2) with the explanation that both loops have complexity O(n). I am confused by why this isn't O(n!), given that the inner loop will run first 0 times, then 1, 2, 3 and so on until n-1 times.

Comment: How are you getting `n!` out of that?  The factorial is the *product* of the first `n` numbers, not their sum...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Big O, how do you calculate/approximate it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3255/big-o-how-do-you-calculate-approximate-it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The inner loop will run O(Sigma(n)) times or O(n^2).

If

- the first iteration runs 0 times and the last one n-1 times,
- the second iteration runs 1 time and the next to last n-2 times,
- the third iteration to 2 times an the second from last n-3 times,
  etc

then they average out to to (n-1) that happens (n/2) times - or O(n^2)

Comment: Thank you! Got confused by the changing loop condition :)